# How to combine the first 8 rows from two different MS Excel sheets together into separate sheet?

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel

I have two MS Excel files. Each file is divided into numbers of sheets say 1 to 100. I want to copy the first 8 rows from each pair of sheets with the same name, such as sheet1 from file1 and sheet1 from file2, into a separate sheet or in one of the two sheets.
as  suggested by **K7AAY**,  let suppose that the two XLSX files are  Able & Baker, both w/ 100 tabs, or sheets. 1) the sheets do not have title rows 2) I wish to copy rows 1-8 from Able and Baker to make a new sheet, Charlie, w/ 100 sheets, each sheet w/ the copied rows from Able(1-8 rows) & Baker(1-8 rows)

Comment: actual Excel sheets or a CSV files?

Comment: actual Excel sheets

Comment: no even with windows its ok

Comment: _Mohsen El-Tahawy_, you have 2 XLSX files, Able & Baker, both w/ 100 tabs, or sheets. 1) Do the sheets have title rows? 2) Do you wish to copy rows 1-8 from Able and Baker, or rows 2-9 (if there's a title row)? 3) Do you wish to make a new sheet, Charlie, w/ 100 sheets, each sheet w/ the copied rows from Able(x) & Baker(x) where x = the sheet the rows were copied from, out of Able and Baker? 4) Or, do you wish to add 100 new sheets to Able so that Able(100+x) holds eight rows from Able(x) and Baker(x)? Please click [edit] and clarify items 1-4 in the original question, not in an added comment.

Comment: I clarified what you want